# Making a function that converts specific pandas columns into len and making a new dataframe based on those values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to programming.
I'm doing a small project with pandas, and I need to create a function that, using a dataframe and 2 columns from that dataframe, outputs two dataframes.

```
dataframe = df

def string_filter(dataframe, dataframest1, dataframest2):
    dataframe0 = dataframe[dataframe[dataframest2].notnull()]
       
    dataframe0[ dataframest1 + ' refined '] = dataframe0[dataframest1].str.len()
    dataframe0[ dataframest2 + ' refined '] = dataframe0[dataframest2].str.len()
    print(dataframe0)
    
    x == dataframe0[ dataframest1 + ' refined ']
    z == dataframe0[ dataframest2 + ' refined ']
   
    dataframe1 = dataframe0[x | z != 1] 
    dataframe2 = dataframe0[x | z == 1] 
    
    return(dataframe1, dataframe2)

string_filter(dataframe, 'c1', 'c2')
```

Whenever I input c1 and c2 as a string, I'm always get this error message:

```
KeyError: ('c1', 'c2')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 string_filter(dataframe, "c1","c2")
```

How do I fix it so when I input dataframest1, dataframest2 as strings I get two dataframes?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output.

Comment: should the `x == ...` be `x = ...`? and the same for z?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

def string_filter(df, col1, col2):

```
flt = (df[col1].str.len()==1) & (df[col2].str.len()==1)
df1 = df[flt]
df2 = df[~flt]

return(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).